# Can anyone 1-line this Scala code (preferably with FP?)

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Sup  y'all.  The below feels like a tragic waste of Scala.  Can anyone save this code?

```
    val tokenSplit = token.split(":")(1)
    val candidateEntityName = tokenSplit.substring(0,tokenSplit.length-1)
    if(!candidateEntityName.equals(entityName)) removeEnd = true
```

Comment: What does this code actually accomplish? E.g. why do you need a removeEnd flag? How does `token` relate to `entityName`? Can you provide some input + expected output? It would clear things up a bit.

Comment: since strings are 0 based: does "tokenSplit.substring(0,tokenSplit.length-1)" have any effect?

Comment: @Stefan scala> "ASD".substring(0,"ASD".length-1)
res0: java.lang.String = AS

Comment: k, if you wanna get rid of the last char "dropRight(1)" might look more functional

Comment: @krivachy sure ... the input is a token, possibly an OpenNLP begin entity tag.. e.g. <START:myEntity> .  I'm doing some string processing and this is in a loop processing lines.  If the myEntity doesn't match entityName, I want to remove its corresponding <END> tag later.  If you can one-line all that, kudos to you!

Comment: @Stefan, hey thanks man!  you found me a drop-in replacement for Python's -1 index.  That got me down to 1 line on the above!  If you add your answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is (You don't need to use `equals`):

```
val removeEnd = token.split(":")(1).init != entityName
```

Comment: Yeah... a bad habit reasserting itself as I'm dealing with a Java package and thus Java examples.  I've heard of plenty of bugs caused by Java's == vs .equals for Strings, but never a case where that difference was useful.

Answer (score 2):

should be sth like: (untested)

```
val removeEnd = !(token.split(":")(1).dropRight(1).equals(entityName))
```

or:

```
val removeEnd = !(token.split(":").last.dropRight(1).equals(entityName))
```

Comment: This actually does something else than the original code. Suppose `removeEnd` was `true` before the execution of the code.

Comment: And there are actually some other things I do that I'm not showing, but the central idea of taking that from 3 lines to 1 is there.

Answer (score 2):

A different solution using regex's to match on the input. It also handles the case where the data isn't as expected (you could of course extend your regex to suite your needs).

```
val removeEnd = """<(\w+):(\w+)>""".r.findFirstMatchIn(token).map(!_.group(2).equals(entityName)).getOrElse(throw new Exception(s"Can't parse input: $token"))
```

If you want to default to false:

```
val removeEnd = """<(\w+):(\w+)>""".r.findFirstMatchIn(token).exists(!_.group(2).equals(entityName))
```

Comment: Great answer, +1 for showing me how to not double escape the backslash in a regex.